# Sorting numbers with multiple decimals in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

In `bash` using `sort` with the `-n` option doesn't give me the expected result.

```
$ cat numbers | sort -n
1.0
1.1
1.11.4
1.15
1.3
1.3.3
1.4-p1
1.6.1
2.2.10
2.2.2
2.4
2.4.6
```

I tried using `-k1`, `-k1.1n`, etc. (`-k1.3n` gets the order correct only for numbers starting with `1`). It seems there's something very basic I'm missing here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the -t. flag to specify '.' as your separator, and the multiple key position specifiers handles the progressively longer/deeper numbers. I still don't quite understand exactly how it works, but it works ...

```
 sort -t. -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n numbers
```

or

```
 cat numbers | sort -t. -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n
```

Answer (score 25):

There is a special flag for this `-V` for version numbers

```
$ sort -V numbers

1.0
1.1
1.3
1.3.3
1.4-p1
1.6.1
1.11.4
1.15
2.2.2
2.2.10
2.4
2.4.6
```

ps. this option is available in GNU Coreutils and may be missing in other implementations.

Comment: This is not a valid option on OSX.

Comment: As a point of minor interest: the `sort` that comes with OS X actually _is_  GNU `sort`, but it it is very old, and predates support for `-V`; as of OS X 10.11, the version number is `sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93`.

Comment: @mklement0: It appears they've added `-V` to macOS `sort --version 2.3-Apple (99)`.

Answer (score 11):

```
sort -g numbers
```

It will do. As per sort man page, `-g` is meant for numerical sorting:

> -g, --general-numeric-sort
>
> compare according to general numerical value

Answer (score 1):

Try;

sort -g -k1 file

It will definitely work!!!