# UNIX: Sort files by number/version without 0 padding

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, unix

Ultimately, I wanted to set the latest version as an environment variable, so supplementing the selected answer (which provided me the correct sorting):

```
export LATEST_VERSION=$(printf '%s\n' * | sort -rV | head -1)
```

---

I have a directory with the following directory names:

```
ls -1r .
2.0
1.8
16.1
16.0
15.5
15.0
14.5
14.1
14.0
1.3
1.2
1.1.5
1.1.3
1.1.2
```

I would like to sort them to get the latest release version:

```
ls -1r . | head -1
16.1
```

So the underlying order should look like this:

```
16.1
16.0
15.5
15.0
14.5
14.1
14.0
2.0
1.8
1.3
1.2
1.1.5
1.1.3
1.1.2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Simpler the better, but I'm open to any solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Modern GNU sort offers a `-V` flag for sorting according to version number rules:

```
$ printf '%s\n' * | sort -rV
16.1
16.0
15.5
15.0
14.5
14.1
14.0
2.0
1.8
1.3
1.2
1.1.5
1.1.3
1.1.2
```

Note that the above does *not* use `ls`.  As a general rule, [you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

#### Documentation

From `man sort`:

> -V, --version-sort
>    natural sort of (version) numbers within text

The above is from the GNU man page.

[FreeBSD's sort](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sort&sektion=1) also supports `-V`.

#### OSX

Apple's [sort](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sort.1.html) is a GNU sort from the year 2005 which predates support for the `-V` option.  A work-around can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385802/sorting-numbers-with-multiple-decimals-in-bash). (Hat tips: l'L'l, mklement0)

Comment: In `OS X` it's actually a real pain in comparison; I asked a similar question a while back: [solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35385802/499581).

Comment: @l'L'l  Very good.  Answer updated with a link to that question.

Comment: @mklement0 Interesting.  I usually expect Apple to use BSD tools where available but you are right: OSX sort is GNU.  From the only  Apple man page that I found online (10.9), it appears to date from 2005.  I also found a man page for [FreeBSD sort](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sort&sektion=1) and it shows support for `-V`.

Comment: @John1024: Yes, it is curious that the odd - usually ancient - GNU utility comes with OS X. I don't know what guides those decisions and whether they're technology- or license-related. It is unfortunate that OS X apparently keeps up with _neither_ the GNU nor the BSD world in terms of providing (reasonably) recent versions.

Comment: @mklement0 The explanation that I have heard was that Apple won't use GPL v3 software.  I have no explanation for the failure to keep up with BSD releases.

Comment: Wow, perfect! Thank you for your thorough answer.

Answer (score -1):

FWIW, I'm in Mac OS right now, and haven't booted over to linux to test.
But, it looks like sort with the numeric option has the smarts to do it:

But, I have a directory with your subdirectories in it, and ls sorts it badly:

```
/Users/thedave/tmp $ ls -1r
2.0
16.1.12
16.1
16.0
15.5
15.0
14.5
14.1
14.0
1.8
1.3
1.2
1.1.5
1.1.3
1.1.2
1.1
1.0.1
1.0
```

sort(1) accepts '-n' for numeric and '-r' for reverse:

```
/Users/thedave/tmp $ ls | sort -rn
16.1.12
16.1
16.0
15.5
15.0
14.5
14.1
14.0
2.0
1.8
1.3
1.2
1.1.5
1.1.3
1.1.2
1.1
1.0.1
1.0
```

Comment: This will fail on `OS X` with numbers such as `1.13.1`, `1.11.10`, `14.15.10`, etc.

Comment: Sorting version numbers is fundamentally different from numerical sorting: numerically, `1.9` is greater than `1.10`, but in terms of version numbers, it is the opposite (leaving aside the fact that a floating-point interpretation of a version string breaks down fundamentally with _3_ or more version components). No `sort` implementation will ever sort version numbers correctly with an option geared towards numerical sorting.