# bash sorting numbers with decimals

Tags: bash, sorting, numeric

I have a file like so:

```
1.1
3.2
1.2
1.10
```

I would like to sort the file so that it looks like so:

```
1.1
1.2
1.10
3.2
```

In other words, 1.10 is bigger than 1.2

I tried:

```
sort -nk 1,1 file
```

But I keep getting this, which is not what I want

```
1.1
1.10
1.2
3.2
```

Thanks

Comment: On Linux (or, more accurately, with GNU `sort`), there's an option `-g` or `--general-numeric-sort`.  I've not played with it.

Comment: On second thoughts, you're not interested in treating the value as a number, because numerically, 1.10 is the same as 1.1 and is smaller than 1.2.  So, the `-g` option is no help.  The `-V` option treats components as components of a version; that works if you have it available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sort:

```
sort -t "." -n -k1,1 -k2,2 file
```

Output:

```
1.1
1.2
1.10
3.2
```

Comment: This works correctly because of the requirement that 10 sorts after 2, which is not a numeric sort.  It could get tricky in more general contexts where the numbers have more varied numbers of digits (12.1, 2.345) and, in particular, are embedded in fields between other delimiters: `a 12.1 b` etc.  I'm not sure there's an easy fix for the latter, other than `-V`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `-V` option.

```
sort -V numbers
```

However this option is only in GNU Coreutils and could be absent from other implementation.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35386002/1107536